# Can one use cooked egg to make fried eggs (sunny side up)?

Tags: baking, eggs, chemistry, hard-boiled-eggs, fried-eggs

As a kid, I never really liked cooked eggs, but fried ones. Naturally, I've always wondered if cooked eggs could be reused to make fried eggs with sunny side up instead of using new raw ones. I thought it was probably a really stupid question, but then I've found these related questions:

- [Is there any way to bring an egg to its natural state (not boiled)
  after you cook it?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/75148)
- [Can one bake a cake with a cooked egg?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/75177)

Now, obviously, it seems a very tall order to get runny yolk if it's already cooked, but **what is the closest thing we can get?** How close can we get to dipping bread into yolk?

Comment: Considering the answer to "can you unboil an egg?" is "no", I feel that the answer to this should be obviously also... "no".

Comment: Hi CuriousCupcake. Welcome to Seasoned Advice! No question is a stupid question, but you're right. This is a tall order. It may help us provide better answers if you help us understand why you'd want to do this. Why wouldn't you just cook the egg to your preference in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a clear duplicate. We're totally fine with basic questions, but basic questions have basic answers (in this case "you can't un-cook it at all") so I don't think we need too many permutations of them. If there's really something different you're trying to find out, feel free to clarify and we'll see if folks want to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, there's no way to actually uncook the egg or change it from a boiled egg to a fried one - even the method used in the question about un-boiling only referred to whites.  You might be able to alter the texture and perhaps presentation to make your boiled egg look similar to a fried one, if that helps?

Well, solid whites are solid whites - I would expect the texture to be pretty similar from boiled to fried, though you might slice them thinly and fry them if you want the extra grease, hardened edges and browning in your egg whites.  Additionally, if you have them sliced thinly, and lay them overlapping on a very hot oiled pan, you might encourage them to stick together (with browned and hardened bits holding the pieces together) in a shape similar to fried egg whites, although it will still be more fragile and prone to breaking at the seams.

Yolk is trickier, since it won't un-set into liquid once it has set up - even the process noted in un-boiling an egg was only for egg whites.  A hard boiled egg is dry enough to act as a paste, so just mashing it won't do - on the other hand, adding some liquid (perhaps butter for flavor and color) and blending into a thick liquid could get you a looser, still egg-flavored and buttery-tasty sauce to dip your toast in, very similar to dipping in just yolk.  As a bonus, you would likely have more yolk-sauce than you would actual yolk, so you get extra dipping action.

I've used set yolks to make a sauce (although that was gelatinized by drying, not set by boiling), and the result was very thick - it took a lot of liquid and still wanted to set up as a paste when I let it sit.  So a set-yolk sauce may turn out to need quite a bit of liquid to reach runny yolk consistency, or it may have a tendency to re-thicken quickly.  But I think it would still be possible.

Comment: I suspect that you could get a runny yolk with only adding a little bit of a strong acid.  Probably not edible, though.